# Определить в предложении количество слов, которые НЕ содержат символ "а"

Tags: delphi, pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

> Определить в предложении количество слов, которые НЕ содержат символ "а". Вывести все эти слова и исходную символьную строку.

Я не понимаю, как посмотреть полностью слово и определить, есть ли в слове буква "а". Вот код:

```
var
    s: string;
    i,k: integer;
begin
  readln(s);
  s:= s + ' ';
  k:= 0;
  for i:= 1 to length(s) do
    begin
      if not(s[i] in [' ',',','.','?','!']) then
        if (pos(s[i],'a') = 0) then k:=k+1; 
    end;
  writeln(k);
end.
```

Comment: Воспользоваться функцией поиска подстроки (`Pos()`). Или заменить все "а" на пустую строку и сравнить длину исходного и после замены. Или ещё чего придумать.

Answer (score 1):

```
## ReadString.ToWords.Where(Слово -> not Слово.Contains('а')).Print(', ')
```

Comment: **НЕ** содержат символ "а".

Comment: сейчас поправим)

Comment: вставить not - секундное дело